# Dropping a multilevel index in columns to a single level

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have a dataframe that looks this after doing groupby on it by major_discipline :

[image]

Now i want to bring the column name in the same line as the 0th column name i.e. major_discipline.
I have tried using droplevel but its not working. I have m.droplevel(1, axis=1) but its is giving me an error. I am new to Python and learning it. Please help me with the solution.

Comment: `df=df.reset_index()`?

Comment: So you want the indices to be `Arts_PR_mfd`, `Business Degree_PR_mjd` and so on?